# Calculate Hashes in Azure Data Factory

Tags: azure-data-factory

We have a requirement where we want to copy the files and folders from on premise to the Azure Blob Storage. Before copying the files I want to calculate the hashes and put that in a file at the source location.
We want this to be done using Azure Data Factory. I am not finding any option in Azure Data Factory to calculate the hashes for a file system type of objects. I am able to find the hashes for a blob once its landed at destination. 
Can some one guide me how this can be achieved.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use data flows in data factory to transform the data.
In a mapping data flow you can just add a column using derived column with an expression using for example the md5() or sha2() function to produce a hash.

Comment: Yes, it works with files of multiple formats - for example CSV and PARQUET

Comment: I think the question is whether this works at the file level, and the answer is no. The Data Flow hashing would only work at the row/column level.

Comment: With the new integration runtime version, there is an option to check the data inconsistency and set the option to skip the file copy if the files are not consistent which worked for me.